# Binding multiple controls to the same datasource in a ASP.Net WebForm

Tags: asp.net, ado.net, sqldatareader

How can I bind multiple controls to the same data source?

I get data from a table via a stored procedure call and want all controls to bind to that data.

The dropdownlist binds successfully but the others do not.
To get it to work I have to create a separate function for each control and call the stored procedure and bind.

```
    private void BindServerControls()
    {
        string strErrorMessage = "";

        SqlDataReader LanguagesDataReader = null;

        try
        {
            dbFunc.OpenDB();

            SqlCommand LanguagesCmd = new SqlCommand("dbo.SelectAllLanguages", dbFunc.objConn);
            LanguagesCmd.Parameters.Clear();
            LanguagesCmd.CommandType = CommandType.StoredProcedure;

            LanguagesDataReader = LanguagesCmd.ExecuteReader();

            if (LanguagesDataReader.HasRows == true)
            {
                // Bind a dropdownlist.
                DropDownList1.DataSource = LanguagesDataReader;
                DropDownList1.DataTextField = "ProgrammingLanguage";
                DropDownList1.DataValueField = "ID";
                DropDownList1.DataBind();
                DropDownList1.Items.Insert(0, "Choose...");

                // Bind a list of Radio buttons.
                RadioButtonList1.DataSource = LanguagesDataReader;
                RadioButtonList1.DataTextField = "ProgrammingLanguage";
                RadioButtonList1.DataValueField = "ID";
                RadioButtonList1.DataBind();

                // Bind a ListBox.
                ListBox1.DataSource = LanguagesDataReader;
                ListBox1.DataTextField = "ProgrammingLanguage";
                ListBox1.DataValueField = "ID";
                ListBox1.DataBind();

                // Bind a CheckBoxList.
                CheckBoxList1.DataSource = LanguagesDataReader;
                CheckBoxList1.DataTextField = "ProgrammingLanguage";
                CheckBoxList1.DataValueField = "ID";
                CheckBoxList1.DataBind();

                // Bind a BulletList.
                BulletedList1.DataSource = LanguagesDataReader;
                BulletedList1.DataTextField = "ProgrammingLanguage";
                BulletedList1.DataValueField = "ID";
                BulletedList1.DataBind();
            }
            else
            {
                Status.Text = "There are currently no entries in the 
                database.";
            }
        }
        catch (Exception ex)
        {
            Status.Text = "Unable to get the entries from the database.";
        }
        finally
        {
            if (LanguagesDataReader != null)
            {
                LanguagesDataReader.Close();
            }

            dbFunc.CloseDB();
        }
    }
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Instead of binding a dataReader object load data in DataTable and then use it for binding

```
DataTable dtLanguages = new DataTable();
using(SqlDataReader LanguagesDataReader = LanguagesCmd.ExecuteReader()) {
  dtLanguages.Load(LanguagesDataReader);
}

if(dtLanguages.Rows.Count > 0) {
// Bind a dropdownlist.
                DropDownList1.DataSource = dtLanguages;
                DropDownList1.DataTextField = "ProgrammingLanguage";
                DropDownList1.DataValueField = "ID";
                DropDownList1.DataBind();
                DropDownList1.Items.Insert(0, "Choose...");
 }
```

The reason is that DataReader is sequential,  forward-only connected datasource and once you finished traversing data through it you can not go back to start and read again.

Comment: Also, note that with sqldatareader wrapped inside using block I don't have to worry about disposing it off because as soon as control jumps out of the using block the data reader will be disposed